# Updating Picklist Values Case-sensitively through metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, picklist

I would love to be able to update picklist values through the Metadata API.  However, some of my changes are nothing but case-correction (e.g., replacing, "Hi there" with "Hi There").

I understand from multiple sources ([RTFM here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_picklist.htm)) that it's impossible to remove picklist values through the Metadata API.  Is there a way to replace values with their case-corrected versions, or even just to add the case corrected versions?

Comment: related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/salesforce-mass-update-picklist-values

Comment: related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/metadata-api-updating-a-recordtypes-picklist?rq=1

Comment: Is your issue better stated if I say, you are looking to replace/update existing picklist values only if they don't match my new/revised values (case sensitive)?

Comment: @James that's the same issue.  Whether it's better-stated or not is a question to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Using the metadata api apex wrapper  (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)
you can modify values of picklist.

Steps are as following:

1- Deploy the metadata api apex wrapper into your org.

2- Modify the CustomValue class included in the MetadataService class including this new values:

```
public virtual class CustomValue extends Metadata {
        public String type = 'CustomValue';
        public String fullName;
        private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
            public String color;
        public Boolean default_x;
        public String description;
        public Boolean isActive;
        public String label;
        private String[] color_type_info = new String[]{'color',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
            private String[] default_x_type_info = new String[]{'default',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
                private String[] description_type_info = new String[]{'description',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
                    private String[] isActive_type_info = new String[]{'isActive',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
                        private String[] label_type_info = new String[]{'label',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
                            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{SOAP_M_URI,'true','false'};
                                private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','color','default_x','description','isActive','label'};
                                    }
```

3-Create your code to modify your picklist values as desired. I attach a code to for example modify the value 'WebCampaign2019'
 of

```
Source_Specification__c
```

picklist of the object Account to be 'WEBCAMPAIGN2019'.

```
        String picklistapiname = 'Account.Source_Specification__c';
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();   
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        MetadataService.CustomField customField = (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { picklistapiname}).getRecords()[0];
        System.debug(customField.valueSet);

        for(MetadataService.CustomValue picklistValue : customField.valueSet.ValueSetDefinition.value){
            if(picklistValue.fullName!=null &&  picklistValue.fullName.equals('WebCampaign2019')){
                picklistValue.fullName = 'WEBCAMPAIGN2019';
                picklistValue.Label = 'WEBCAMPAIGN2019';
            }
        }
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> lstResults = service.updateMetadata( new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
```

4- Done.

[image: PicklistValues Before Executing Script]
[image: ExecutingScript]
[image: Refreshing PicklistValues After executing Script]

Comment: Does this work for the replacement of options of a different case?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's because of the choice of words, but I don't understand what you mean, could you rephrase it, please?

Comment: The original question asked how to change the case of a picklist option using the metadata api. For example, SUPER when Super is already an option.

Comment: The option on the picklist is modificable.The issue is that the data is not updated acordingly since the old value is moved to inactive values and I couldn't achieve to delete picklist values using the wrapper metadata api. If that was possible I think it would be smooth to do a full substitution of picklist metadata values and data values on DB. But atm I only know how to substitut metadata values on the picklist.

Comment: Or simply correcting the case of Super to SUPER